# Only first DataAnnotation validation being applied

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations

I'm currently working on a Winforms application written in VB.NET and implementing the Entity Framework (4.4). I want to add validation attributes to my entities so that I can validate them on the UI - just as I do in MVC.

I have created my 'Buddy Class' which contains an IsValid method and points to a 'MetaData' class that contains the data annotations.
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
    Imports System.ComponentModel

```
<MetadataTypeAttribute(GetType(ProductMetadata))>
Public Class Product

    Private _validationResults As New List(Of ValidationResult)
    Public ReadOnly Property ValidationResults() As List(Of ValidationResult)
        Get
        Return _validationResults
    End Get
End Property

Public Function IsValid() As Boolean

    TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(New AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(GetType(Product), GetType(ProductMetadata)), GetType(Product))

    Dim result As Boolean = True

    Dim context = New ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing)

    Dim validation = Validator.TryValidateObject(Me, context, _validationResults)

    If Not validation Then
        result = False
    End If

    Return result

End Function

End Class

Friend NotInheritable Class ProductMetadata

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Product Name is Required", AllowEmptyStrings:=False)>
    <MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage:="Too Long")>
    Public Property ProductName() As Global.System.String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Description is Required")>
    <MinLength(20, ErrorMessage:="Description must be at least 20 characters")>
    <MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage:="Description must not exceed 60 characters")>
    Public Property ShortDescription As Global.System.String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Notes are Required")>
    <MinLength(20, ErrorMessage:="Notes must be at least 20 characters")>
    <MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage:="Notes must not exceed 1000 characters")>
    Public Property Notes As Global.System.String

End Class
```

The first line in the IsValid method registers the MetaData class (only way I could find that actually worked - otherwise no annotations were honored!). I then use the System.ComponentModel.Validator.TryValidateObject method to perform the validation.

When I call the IsValid method on an instance with an empty (null/nothing) ProductName the validation fails and the ValidationResults collection is populated with the correct error message. So far so good.....

However, if I call IsValid on an instance with a ProductName which is longer than 50 characters the validation passes despite the MaxLength attribute!

Also, if I call IsValid on an instance with a valid ProductName (not empty and not more than 50 characters) but without a ShortDescription the validation passes even though there is a Required annotation on that property.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the other method signature for `TryValidateObject()` and explicitly set `validateAllProperties` to true:

```
Dim validation = Validator.TryValidateObject(
        Me, context, _validationResults, true)
```

Comment: Note to self - always check the overloads! Thanks @qujck :-)

Comment: @DilbertDave TBH I don't understand why there's a method version that only does some of the checks!

Comment: Me neither - maybe it's a feature ;-)